# Unable to call CUDA half precision functions from the host

Tags: cuda, precision

I am trying to do some FP16 work that will have both CPU and GPU backend. I researched my options and decided to use [CUDA's half precision converter and data types.](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC) The ones I intent to use are specified as both `__device__` and `__host__` which according to my understanding (and the official [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#host)) should mean that the functions are callable from both HOST and DEVICE code. I wrote a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

int main() {
  const float a = 32.12314f;
  __half2 test = __float2half2_rn(a);
  __half test2 = __float2half(a);
  return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile it I get:

```
nvcc cuda_half2.cu 
cuda_half2.cu(6): error: calling a __device__ function("__float2half2_rn") from a __host__ function("main") is not allowed

cuda_half2.cu(7): error: calling a __device__ function("__float2half") from a __host__ function("main") is not allowed

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000013b8_00000000-4_cuda_half2.cpp4.ii".
```

The only thing that comes to mind is that my CUDA is 9.1 and I'm reading the documentation for 9.2 but i can't find an older version of it, nor can I find anything in the [changelog](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html). Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideas?

Switch to CUDA 9.2

Your code compiles without error on CUDA 9.2, but throws the errors you indicate on CUDA 9.1.  If you have CUDA 9.1 installed, then the documentation for it is already installed on your machine. On a typical linux install, it will be located in `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/doc`. If you look at `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/doc/pdf/CUDA_Math_API.pdf` you will see that the corresponding functions are only marked `__device__`, so this change was indeed made between CUDA 9.1 and CUDA 9.2